# iframes for ads? getting user information?

Tags: php, javascript, iframe, cookies

I was trying to do something like Google's Adsense. I believe they use javascript? But is using iFrame a good idea to have someone put on their site if they want to display ads? Would iFrames able to capture user's data information such as cookies (how adsense works, they get users cookies--that's why they can display ads of sites you've visited, correct me if I'm wrong)?

If this works, how would I able to get users cookies? Is it possible? How does google get users cookies?

Thanks for your help in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> (how adsense works, they get users cookies--that's why they can display ads of sites you've visited, correct me if I'm wrong)?

You are wrong. Google can only access Google's cookies. It's a big point in cookie security; no browser will allow you to get to other sites' cookies. Google can use cookies to identify you, but can't use them to see your behaviour on non-Google sites.

AdSense knows what you've been browsing by checking what links you click on Google Search and other services, what Ads you click on, what pages you visit that have AdSense in them (`window.top.document.location`) and which pages you visit them from (`window.top.document.referrer`), and probably more methods that people smarter than me at Google come up with :)

**EDIT**: as shown in comments, in fact one *can't* rely on `top` properties.

Comment: Actually Google can't access those properties from inside the iframe since that would violate the [same origin policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy) check it yourself, set up an iframe as a test and open a domain unrelated to the one you're testing on and try to access those properties with js. The url you're on, or more specifically, what location, is conveyed with the url being loaded. (who upvoted this?)

Comment: @sg3e: I might be wrong about `referrer`, but I'm pretty sure `top.location` works. See the first snippet in Google's [Browser Security Handbook](http://code.google.com/p/browsersec/wiki/Part2#Arbitrary_page_mashups_(UI_redressing\)) - it wouldn't work if what you say about `top.location` was true. Then again, it is late, and I do admit I haven't tried for myself.

Comment: I actually did try for myself before posting my comment. It might have been a security hole in ancient browsers but in this day and age we can't realy count on those techniques if 80% uses a secure browser and we still want to track them. Use chrome, go to http://jsfiddle.net/sg3s/j8sbX/25/ (jsfiddle for another question which comes in handy here as it has an iframe) and open dev tools, switch to the right frame (myiframe, right of the 'clear console' button) and test what you said. All the other errors can be ignored but are actually somewhat related.

Answer (score 0):

No you can't get these cookies. They're stored to be readable only by the domain AdSense uses to log people.

This is why an iframe is used, it allows google to load a specific url on a domain they control, the url contains an identifier telling them what AdSense campaign is being used.

Besides, the cookie which is present (but not accessible by you) doesn't contain any information about the user itself. It is instead just an identifier to link the person to data which is already present on the google servers.